# Left join a list of irregular lists to a dataframe based on list names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join, tibble

Let's say I have a `data.frame` called `countDF`:

`> countDF
      date count complete
1 20180124    16    FALSE
2 20180123    24     TRUE
3 20180122    24     TRUE
4 20180121    24     TRUE
5 20180120    23    FALSE
6 20180119    23    FALSE
7 20180118    24     TRUE`

Which looks like this under the hood:

```
> dput(countDF)
structure(list(date = c("20180124", "20180123", "20180122", "20180121", 
"20180120", "20180119", "20180118"), count = c(16L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 23L, 23L, 24L), complete = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L), .Names = c("date", 
"count", "complete"))
```

And this list:

```
> last7D_missingHours
$`20180124`
[1]  3 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

$`20180120`
[1] 18

$`20180119`
[1] 7
```

Which looks like this:

```
> dput(last7D_missingHours)
structure(list(`20180124` = c(3L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L), `20180120` = 18L, `20180119` = 7L), .Names = c("20180124", 
"20180120", "20180119"))
```

I would like to make a `data.frame` (or, perhaps `data_frame`) that joins the latter to the former with `left_join(countDF, last7D_missingHours, by = c('date' = names(last7D_missingHours)))` and have `NA` in the `date` rows that do not match, like this:

`> countDF
      date count complete missingHour
1 20180124    16    FALSE 3 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
2 20180123    24     TRUE NA
3 20180122    24     TRUE NA
4 20180121    24     TRUE NA
5 20180120    23    FALSE 18
6 20180119    23    FALSE 7
7 20180118    24     TRUE NA`

I could probably hack through this with recursive subsetting I'm guessing, but wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions for a more optimal approach, since I know `tibbles` have come quite a long way recently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the missing hours into a list-column in a `tibble` with the other variable as the dates, and then just `left_join`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

countDF <- structure(list(date = c("20180124", "20180123", "20180122", "20180121", 
                                   "20180120", "20180119", "20180118"), 
                          count = c(16L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L), 
                          complete = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), 
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L), .Names = c("date", "count", "complete"))

last7D_missingHours <- structure(list(`20180124` = c(3L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
                                                     23L), `20180120` = 18L, `20180119` = 7L), .Names = c("20180124", 
                                                                                                          "20180120", "20180119"))

lst_tbl <- tibble(date = c("20180124", "20180120", "20180119"),
                  missingHour = last7D_missingHours)

left_join(countDF, lst_tbl)
#> Joining, by = "date"
#>       date count complete                   missingHour
#> 1 20180124    16    FALSE 3, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
#> 2 20180123    24     TRUE                          NULL
#> 3 20180122    24     TRUE                          NULL
#> 4 20180121    24     TRUE                          NULL
#> 5 20180120    23    FALSE                            18
#> 6 20180119    23    FALSE                             7
#> 7 20180118    24     TRUE                          NULL
```

I end up with `NULL` rather than `NA`, which I think makes more sense, so I didn't try to change them just to get what you asked for.

Comment: Works as advertised, and I think you're right about the `NULL`s, too.  Thank you!  I'll see if anyone else has any thoughts but this will likely do it.

Comment: You can simplify `date = c("20180124", "20180120", "20180119")` to `date = names(last7D_missingHours)` which is more scaleable.